# Prevent a href=# on click altering the URL?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link that jumps to a particular part of a page.

```
 <a href="#secondPage/2" class="projectLink">Project Infomation</a>
```

On click the URL changes to **website.com/project.html#secondPage/2**

I'm trying to prevent **#secondPage/2** being added to URL.

The current script I'm using is not working.

```
 <script>
    $('#secondPage/2').click(function(event
    ){
        even.preventDefault();
    });
  </script>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: missing a t on `even.preventDefault();` but then, how are you going to "navigate" there?

Comment: missing `t` didn't resolve issue the answer below did .`#secondPage/2` is determined by the fullpage.js script I'm using.

Answer (score 4):

You are not using the proper jQuery selector for this to work.
You could either try using

```
$('a[href=#secondPage/2]').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

OR

```
$('a.projectLink').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

OR you can add an `ID` to your link and use that as the selector in your jQuery object. In that case your **HTML** would be something like this...

```
<a href="#secondPage/2" id="secondPage-2" class="projectLink">Project Infomation</a>
```

and your **jQuery/Javascript** would be

```
$('a#secondPage-2').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape / with double backslash along with correcting your attribute selector.

```
$('a[href=#secondPage\\/2]').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/